# How to get key value based on id from list of dictionaries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is my code

```
public class model 
{
    public model();
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Data { get; set; }
}

List<Dictionary<string,string>> data1;

var data1 = await get<model>();

data1[0]=[0][{id,101}]
         [1][{name,one}]

data1[1]=[0][{id,102}]
         [1][{name,two}]

data1[2]=[0][{id,103}]
         [1][{name,three}]
```

In the code i have a list of dictionaries with id and name keys. now i have id=102 search in list of dictionaries and get name value related on id using linq query.

Comment: I don't understand.  Each of your dictionaries could have the id 102 one or zero times.  What do you want the output to be?  Also your `Dictionary<string, string>` has a string key, not an int key.

Comment: i want name value based on id. eg:- id=102  var result=two.

Comment: Why are you storing each ID `KeyValuePair` inside a different dicitonary? What's the point of that. You could simply have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. You're not taking advantage of a `Dictionary` at all here, just adding overhead.

Comment: you have List<Dictionary<string,string>>  .for eg :- list[0] have key and value like {'102','one','103','two'}.list[1] may have same data as before or different. so what data you want ? each dictionary data is unique or different ?if you pass id like 102 , do you want to take all the record from each dictionary ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = data1.First(d => d["id"] == "102")["name"];
```

You find the first list element where the key "id" maps to value "102", and then get the value for key "name".

Comment: Note this will take the first match, ignoring any other match.  Seems to be what the OP wants, as best I can tell.

Comment: @EricJ.  Yes, I'm not sure either.

Comment: @durgasivakishoremopuru You may want to accept the answer by clicking the grey check box next to it to indicate that the solution has worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> data1 = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();


            Dictionary<string, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic1.Add("101", "one");
            dic1.Add("102", "two");
            data1.Add(dic1);

            dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic1.Add("201", "2one");
            dic1.Add("202", "2two");
            data1.Add(dic1);

            dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic1.Add("301", "3one");
            dic1.Add("302", "3two");
            data1.Add(dic1);

            //try your values here
            var id = "201";
            var s=data1.Where(c => c.Keys.Contains(id)).Select(c => c.Keys.Where(p => p == id).Select(p => c[p]).FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```